# Проблема со звуком Unity3D 5.5

Tags: c#, unity3d, аудио

Вечер добрый, такой вопрос : существует корутина, которая вызывается каждый кадр и через полсекунды возвращает скорость изменения переменной. Задача состоит в том , чтобы воспроизводить звук (клип) , только пока данная скорость больше порога. Звучит просто, но когда я в апдейте делаю условие
    `if (dx>porog)
    src.play();
else
    src.pause();`
 при постоянном `dx` большим порога, происходит следующее : каждый раз звук играет по новой , то есть тупо заедает на первом фрейме и крутит его. При вызове из корутины происходит то же самое. Проблема кажется элементарной, но битый день уже ничего не могу придумать. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Добавте фрагмент кода, в котором у вас возникли затруднения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо 'src.play()' используй 'src.unpause()'. Play запускает звук с нуля, а тебе надо с паузы снять.